# Hilbert class field and complex conjugation.

Tags: number-theory

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic number field, and $L$ be the Hilbert class field over $K$. I would like to show that $[L:K]=[L\cap \mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q}]$.

I think I understand why this would be true, but I cannot see a good argument to draw this conclusion. Here is my "fractured argument". Let $c:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be the complex conjugation. With the help of basic Galois theory one can show that $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois. What I need here is to prove that $\text{Gal}(L/L\cap\mathbb{R})=\langle c\rangle$. If I can show this then using the fact that $\text{Gal}(L/L\cap\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $\text{Gal}(L/K)$, I should be able to get it done. I know that this is probably the silliest part of the entire body of the proof, but for some reason I cannot convince myself that the fixed field of $\langle c\rangle$ in $L$ is $L\cap\mathbb{R}$.

Any suggestion/help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are currently reading Cox's *Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$*. As a consequence, all number fields are assumed to be subfields of $\mathbb{C}$, i.e., we have $K \subseteq L \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Given this, it actually makes sense to speak of $L \cap \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, we may consider the complex conjugation automorphism $c \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, and prove (using properties of the Hilbert class field) that it restricts to an automorphism $c \colon L \to L$. (Using this observation, one may deduce that $L \mid \mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension; see Lemma 5.28 in Cox.)

Now we come to the solution of your problem: Since $K$ is (imaginary) quadratic, we have
$$[L:\mathbb{Q}] = [L:K] \cdot [K:\mathbb{Q}] = 2[L:K].$$
On the other hand, we also have
$$[L:\mathbb{Q}] = [L:L^{\langle c \rangle}] \cdot [L^{\langle c \rangle}:\mathbb{Q}] = 2 [L^{\langle c \rangle}:\mathbb{Q}],$$
where we used the general fact that $[L:L^{\langle c \rangle}] = |\langle c \rangle| = 2$. So we are done if we can prove that $L^{\langle c \rangle} = L \cap \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, we have $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{C}^{\langle c \rangle}$: Given any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, we may write $z = x+yi$ for certain $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ (where $i \in \mathbb{C}$ is any fixed squareroot of $-1$) and compute that
$c(z) = x-yi$. Comparing real and imaginary parts, we see that $c(z) = z$ is equivalent to $y = 0$ (or in other words, to $z \in \mathbb{R}$) as desired. Given this (and the fact that we regard $L \subseteq \mathbb{C}$), it follows that
$$L^{\langle c \rangle} = \{l \in L \colon c(l) = l\} = \{l \in L \colon l \in \mathbb{C}^{\langle c \rangle} = \mathbb{R} \} = L \cap \mathbb{R}.$$